# Android Studio can't find java package

Tags: java, android-studio

My java Android studio project cannot find imported packages. I simply get the error "cannot resolve symbol xyz" for all of my imports. This is causing hundreds of error messages across my program. [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfyhG.png)